# ROS Answers SE migration: Sensor fusion

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I have a quadrocopter and want to fuse all sensor data (accelerometer, gyroscope, barometer, GPS and heading) to determine the position and pose.

What is the best way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221813/sensor-fusion/) by [oliverkn](https://answers.ros.org/users/25223/oliverkn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some basic googling directly leads me to [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oliverkn](https://answers.ros.org/users/25223/oliverkn/) on 2015-12-01**:
the problem is I don't know how to get the odometry information, which is required for robot_localization